# iTunes U: "Developing Apps for iOS" Senseful to watch if having newer version?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, xcode4.2

I'm pretty new to all that iOS stuff and Objective C- Programming. Since I'm going through a book for learning Objective C, I realized that it might be useful for me to watch some lecture about that topic additionally.

In some older Stackoverflow topics, I found "Developing Apps for iOS" from the Stanford University (http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/developing-apps-for-ios-sd/id395631522). After watching the second lecture, I think about if it's useful to follow the lectures. I'm using XCode 4.2 and it seems like it's different to XCode 4.1 (what he's using). So my questions: Is it useful to follow his lectures? Are there some deep main changes where I'll face much problems and if yes, is there another podcast/video tutorial about the same topic for XCode 4.2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an updated version of the same course that covers Xcode 4.2. And yes, there are *significant* differences between 4.1 and 4.2. You should definitely use the newer one.

Just search for "iPad and iPhone Application Development" in iTunes U. It's taught by Paul Hegarty. You'll want the Fall 2011 course.

**Update**: Here's a link: http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=473757255

Comment: thanks alot! I've searched with the wrong keywords (with the keyword "iOS")...